# redisTemplate.opsForHash.get(key, hashKey) is returning null instead of proper value, due to pipelining

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data, jedis

We are running this command in a multi-client, high-traffic application and it is occasionally returning null even when there is a value for it in Redis:

```
Object result = redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(KEY, hashKey);
```

This is because `JedishHashCommands` has this implementation for `hGet`:

```
public byte[] hGet(byte[] key, byte[] field) {
    Assert.notNull(key, "Key must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(field, "Field must not be null!");

    try {
        if (this.isPipelined()) {
            this.pipeline(this.connection.newJedisResult(this.connection.getRequiredPipeline().hget(key, field)));
            return null;
        } else if (this.isQueueing()) {
            this.transaction(this.connection.newJedisResult(this.connection.getRequiredTransaction().hget(key, field)));
            return null;
        } else {
            return this.connection.getJedis().hget(key, field);
        }
    } catch (Exception var4) {
        throw this.convertJedisAccessException(var4);
    }
}
```

So it looks like whenever we happen to be pipelining or queuing, this `hGet` will return null even if there is a proper value for it stored in Redis. How do we avoid this? Are we not supposed to use `RedisTemplate.opsForHash` ?

Comment: Not sure how to avoid but I can provide a workaround.

Comment: @JohnWilliams I would love to hear the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

A suggested workaround is to wrap the call in a [Spring @Retryable](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) as follows. It will cause a retry when a null is returned. The retry attempts will back-off exponentially.

```
public class RedisRetryWrapper {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;
    
    @Retryable(retryFor = NullReturnException.class, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10))
    public Object opsForHash(Object key, Object hashKey) {
        Object result = redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(key, hashKey);
        if (result == null) {
            throw new NullReturnException();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

`opsForHash` must be called from a class besides `RedisRetryWrapper` to allow the java proxy mechanism to work.

**NullReturnException**

```
public class NullReturnException extends RuntimeException {}
```

**Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>
```